Cannot clone SD card on my Raspberry Pi 3B+
I have some old software running on a headless Raspberry Pi 3B+ with Raspbian 'Jessie' (8.0).
I have tried removing the SD card and copying it with Win32imagewrite, and even with a MAC. Both fail with an IO error.  The Raspbian system runs OK, but wanted to update the SD card since there are a lot of disk writes involved.
I tried RPI-clone and got the following error message While trying to copy the running 16 GB SD card to a new 32 GB SD card.
I tried to make a picture to text capture of the error message, but that didn't work very well so it's been removed from my question.

You are wasting your time trying to do this on Windows (or Mac) using their own proprietary copiers. You NEED a Linux system which supports the partition format to reconstruct. Most of us would do this using the SD Copier on the Pi itself. I am unsure if this was included in ancient Jessie.

If you have 2 sdcard  readers and 2 spare sdcards, new install Bullseye on a sdcard. Boot from it and copy, clone Jessie to the other 32g sdcard. More instructions if you wish.
